# Unity3D - Mesh Collider in imported blender mesh doesn't work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, blender

I'm trying to apply a script that changes the material color when the cursor is on top of the object. Here's the script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ChangeColor : MonoBehaviour {

    public Color startColor;
    public Color mouseOverColor;
    bool mouseOver = false;

    void OnMouseEnter(){
        Debug.Log("START");
        mouseOver = true;
        GetComponent<Renderer>().material.SetColor("_Color",mouseOverColor);
        Debug.Log("TESTE");
    }

    void OnMouseExit(){
        mouseOver = false;
        GetComponent<Renderer>().material.SetColor("_Color", startColor);
    }

}
```

The object is a simple triangle:

[image]

The script only works when the object has a *Sphere Collider* (what i'm looking for is to use a Mesh Collider).

Can someone help me understand how to use it with a Mesh Collider?

Thank you

Comment: Attaching MeshCollider  to an object doesn't mean that this object now has a collider. There is no MeshCollider yet because Unity couldn't generate one. Look very closely and you will seen this error. Click on the Console tab to read more about it

Comment: Do you have any errors in your console related to your script? I can see some from here. Please show us

Comment: @Narevar `Failed to create Convex Mesh from source mesh "Icosphere_204". Source mesh is likely have too many smooth surface regions. Please reduce the surface smoothness of the source mesh. Alternatively turn on Inflate Mesh and increase the Skin Width sufficiently for this mesh.`. I've tried the `Inflate Mesh` option, but it still doesn't work

Comment: this is the only error you have?

Answer (score 0):

According to the Unity's documentation, `OnMouseEnter()` function only works when your Collider is marked as trigger.

Try activating that property and check the documentation too.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseEnter.html

Comment: you can see from screenshot the property is activated

Comment: My Bad I thought convex in my head @vasco_t try to check the property